# Hyper-V Virtual Switch Generic failure

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server, windows-server-2022, virtual-network

I installed Hyper-V on my Server (Windows 2022) but it did not create a virtual network adapter.
I tried many possible fixes like uninstalling and installing it again and running `netcfg -d` but this didn't help.

Those are the errors I'm getting

[Generic failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l9v5.png)

[Event Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRCrf.png)

```
> Log Name:      System
> 
> Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch
> 
> Date:          11/10/2023 12:47:41 PM
> 
> Event ID:      4
> 
> Task Category: (1002)
> 
> Level:         Error
> 
> Keywords:      (128)
> 
> User:          SYSTEM
> 
> Computer:      AD2A7FE
> 
> Description: Failed to initialize VMSwitch driver due to error
> {Operation Failed} The requested operation was unsuccessful.. Event
> Xml: <Event
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">  
> <System>
>     <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VmSwitch" Guid="{67dc0d66-3695-47c0-9642-33f76f7bd7ad}" />
> 
>     <EventID>4</EventID>
>     <Version>0</Version>
>     <Level>2</Level>
>     <Task>1002</Task>
>     <Opcode>0</Opcode>
>     <Keywords>0x8000000000000080</Keywords>
>     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-11-10T11:47:41.9046319Z" />
>     <EventRecordID>317650</EventRecordID>
>     <Correlation />
>     <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="32" />
>     <Channel>System</Channel>
>     <Computer>AD2A7FE</Computer>
>     <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />   </System>   <EventData>
>     <Data Name="Status">3221225473</Data>
>     <Data Name="UniqueEvent">150</Data>   </EventData> </Event>
```

This is what i get when I run `Get-NetAdapter` and `New-VMSwitch VMSwitch -NetAdapterName Ethernet`

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator> New-VMSwitch VMSwitch -NetAdapterName Ethernet
New-VMSwitch : Failed while creating virtual Ethernet switch.
An unexpected error occurred: %%2147749924 (0x80041024).
Failed while creating virtual Ethernet switch.
The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service encountered an unexpected error: %%2147749924 (0x80041024).
At line:1 char:1
+ New-VMSwitch VMSwitch -NetAdapterName Ethernet
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-VMSwitch], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVMSwitch

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connec...      17 Up           D0-**-**-**-**-**         1 Gbps
Ethernet 2                Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Conn...#2      14 Disconnected D0-**-**-**-**-**          0 bps
vEthernet (WSL)           Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3           5 Not Present  00-**-**-**-**-**          0 bps
```

Any help is appreciated <3

Comment: Remove Hyper-V (Control Panel, Programs and Features, Features) and restart.  Add back Hyper-V and check if the adapter is working. I have Hyper-V on a couple workstation machine and the default adapter is always there.

Comment: @John I already tried this it's not showing up...

Comment: Strange.   Try running DISM / SFC:   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @John executed the commands above and remove and installed Hyper-v again but the errors persist

Comment: I checked Server 2022 for compatibility with Hyper-V and of course it is compatible so something appears to have gone wrong with the operating system.